# How to prevent iframe from scrolling to top after clicking empty anchor tags in an iframe in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to figure out why mobile safari chooses to ignore "javascript:void(0);" within my anchor tags and any work arounds. I've already tried putting "#" in the href and just leaving the href completely off to no avail.

My expected behavior is for the text below "Click Me" to appear/disappear and no other behavior.  Everything works fine on my desktop in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE, but in mobile safari the iframe scrolls to the top.  My code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>iOS Click Test</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
<body>
        <div style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; height: 200px;" scrolling="no">
    <iframe style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
                <html>
                    <head>
            <title>iOS Click Test</title>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function ()
            {
                     $('#testClick').click(function() {
                    $('#showText').toggleClass('hidden');
                     });
            });
            </script>
         <style>
        .padding
        {
            height: 2000px;
        }

        .hidden
        {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
            <style type='text/css"></style>
                </head>
            <body>
            <div class='padding'>Top of page</div>
            <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id='testClick'>Click Me</a>
            <p id='showText' class=''>Made visible</p>          
            </div>
            <div class='padding'></div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: try `$('#testClick').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... })`

Comment: Sorry that didn't work either.  Neither does trying to scroll back to the original position after the click happens.

Comment: what if you `return false;` at the end?

Comment: Nope doesn't work either. Just to make sure I'm doing it right, the snippet of code would look something like this: `$('#testClick').click(function(e) { $('#showText').toggleClass('hidden"); return false; });`

Comment: Yeah, maybe if you do both: `$('#testClick').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('#showText').toggleClass('hidden"); return false; });`  If it still doesn't work, what I would do is have the element not be an anchor, change it to a div and style it to look like a link.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be an anchor for 508 compliance so our customers can tab to it.  I can't seem to make that work with a div.  And both the prevent default and return false don't work. It seems like it's a mobile safari bug/default behavior, but I can't seem to prevent it.

Comment: Hmmm, ok thinking outside the box here, what if you did `<a href="#testClick" id='testClick'>Click Me</a>`.  It theoretically should then scroll to itself, which may or may not work.

Comment: Haha, I actually tried that just a minute ago.  Sadly, it didn't work.  It seems like the problem is when change the DOM or add/remove a class on the element, the entire frame refreshes.

Comment: have you tried `$('#showText').hide();` and `$('#showText').show();`?

Comment: Yea I tried that and just setting the css via `$("#showText").css('display', 'none')` to no avail.  It seems like something to do with the iframe as if I were to remove the iframe it works as expected.